# Верстка заголовка

Tags: вёрстка

Каким образом можно сверстать элемент заголовка `h1` так, чтобы у него было подчеркивание снизу, но только на длину нижней строки и только под нижней строкой.
Количество строк/слов будет зависеть от контента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я уже рассматриваю вариант отделения части которая окажется в последней строке в отдельный span на пхп только вот даже не ясно как это реализовать ведь ширина блока с таким заголовком может быть разной

Comment: есть мысли как на js реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой вариант через `h1:after{}`

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline
}
h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #35C2F5;
    content: ""
}
```

Пример:
    http://jsfiddle.net/9jpw0j22/

Comment: не работает в FF